# I want to know all types of actions defined for IntentFilter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-developer-api

I want to know all types of actions defined for IntentFilter.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name=""
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Since they are arbitrary strings, there is an impossibly large number of possible actions. While a number of popular ones are documented on the `Intent` class, there are others in the Android SDK, and any developer can invent their own.

Comment: Ummm...why would you need to know this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look at the Link it contains all about intent filters
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

The name of the action. Some standard actions are defined in the Intent class as ACTION_string constants. To assign one of these actions to this attribute, prepend "android.intent.action." to the string that follows ACTION_. For example, for ACTION_MAIN, use "android.intent.action.MAIN" and for ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, use "android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH".
check this link for more:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#standard-activity-actions